# How to control font size in an eBay listing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to control font size in an eBay listing such that it will look the same (more or less) on Firefox *and* Internet Explorer 8.

To simplify things I just specify a single font size for the entire body text:

```
<body style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px;">
 ...
</body>
```

Yet, while locally (on my PC) the font looks as I want it to look like:

> Firefox 3.6:
>
> [image]
>
> Internet Explorer 8:
>
> [image]

On eBay itself, the font looks much bigger (which is **not** what I want):

> Firefox 3.6 on eBay:
>
> [image]
>
> Internet Explorer 8 on eBay:
>
> [image]

I tried of course different font-size unit specification (`em`, `%`, etc.) but the discrepancy remains.

Why is this happening and how can I get around this (without resorting to posting an image of the text...).

I understand that there might be some collision between eBay's CSS and my HTML (I don't use any CSS, I only use inline style!), but I don't know how to tell eBay **not** to override my style.

Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: You need to use specific enough selectors to override what eBay css you're inheriting. Are you using some kind of feed from eBay for the markup/css?

Comment: @Jared Farrish No, I am not using any feed from eBay, this HTML purely authored by my from scratch. BTW, I don't use any CSS as my understanding that I can't even paste `<head></head>` into what eBay provides as the "product description". All I do is paste `<body></body>`. How do I use "specific enough selectors"? Isn't specifying style for the entire <body> enough?

Comment: If you style the `body` tag, any styles applied to a `p` tag will override yours because your first selector (`body *`) is less specific than the second (just `p`).

Comment: I get the feeling you're pretty new to markup and styling of webpages. Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/css for some good introductory training. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Might be a dirty trick, but have you tried overwriting the CSS using the `!important` declaration?

Like so:

```
foo: bar !important;
```

I would suggest you open up Firebug on Firefox (or Chrome's inspector on Google Chrome) and see what styles are overwriting the ones you added.

Another thing to try is adding those styles (the whole `style=` attribute) to the text blocks itself. If that works, your code just isn't specific enough.

---

Your problem seems to be selector specificity. Here's what that means:

If I have CSS which applies to all of the elements in a document:

```
body * {
  foo: bar;
}
```

It will be overridden by a more specific selector, like this:

```
body p {
  foo: baz;
}
```

Because the `p` is selecting a specific element, while the `*` broadly selects all of them.

When you apply the `style=` attribute, like this `<body style="...`, you are making that CSS very unspecific, like the first chunk of code.

Instead, apply the `style=` attribute to your HTML:

```
<body>
  <p style="...">My content</p>
</body>
```

Try to get it as specific as possible, as specific selectors override non-specific ones.

Comment: @Blender Where do I enter the `!important`? I don't use any CSS as my understanding that I can't even paste `<head></head>` into what eBay provides as the "product description". All I do is paste `<body></body>`

Comment: Right. Pop it in before the semicolon. `color: black;` becomes `color: black !important;`.

Comment: @Blender - I think the OP needs more help than this answer can provide. Read the response to my comment under the question.

Comment: I did. I'm not sure how eBay works with this stuff, but all I can suggest is adding the `style` attributes directly to the text blocks wrapped in `<p>` tags, as that is about as specific as it gets.

Comment: @Blender - Yes, if you fundamentally understand the concepts occurring behind style declarations. Read the response again - I don't get the vibe the OP is well versed in such conceptual notions. To wit, I've been doing CSS for going on nine years and `!important` is still a little hazy. The OP is a total beginner, AFAICT.

Comment: Okay, I'll make my answer a bit more verbose.

Comment: @Blender - Not bad; I think the bigger issue is the OP needs a better understanding of how CSS works, specifically with how the proximity of "selectors" and inline styles affect the ultimate computed style of an element displayed on the screen. Having backed into this particular concept years ago, I can understand it's challenging. The OP should read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Getting_Started/How_CSS_works

Comment: @Jared, that's a pretty good article. Hard to explain CSS without explaining it...

Comment: @Blender - Also, I'm not entirely sure the OP isn't comparing a locally-copied version run off their machine with the one hosted by eBay (on ebay.com). I can't say for sure, but I have my suspicions.

Comment: @Blender - That's why I ultimately decided to vote to close as "too localized".

Comment: @Blender I just tried the `!important` "dirty trick" but it didn't work. I will try the specificity approach now.

Comment: @Blender Specificity worked, thank you! BTW, I didn't even have a single `<p>` in my HTML, the only place I had to add `font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px;` was to the existing `style=` of `<table>` (may help others stumbling upon this thread).

Answer (score 4):

The answers above are all incorrect, or useless.

You should make each element more specific by wrapping your entire auction code in an id element, such as straight after the
    < body >
tag, put

```
<div id="myauction">
```

Insert your auction code here.

```
</div><!-- END OF MYAUCTION -->
</body>
```

If you find that some elements are still not working properly, then put them into yet another id element too, such as

```
<div id="column1">
<div class="itemdetails">
<h2>Item name</h2>
<p>Item description</p>
</div><!-- END OF ITEMDETAILS -->
</div><!-- END OF COLUMN1 -->
```

Then use CSS something like
    #myauction #column1 .itemdetails h2 {color:black; etc...}
    #myauction #column1 .itemdetails p {font-family:Helvetica; etc...}

That will make the h2 and p tags more specific (probably) than anything the Ebay CSS is doing to them.

Blender (above) doesn't know what he's talking about, by the way. Bad advice is worse than no advice.